# How to answer, log and hang up phone with React Native Incall Manager

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make a react native program that can accept phone call, log phone number and hang up the phone using react-native-incall-manager.

My motivation for doing this is to verify phone number by answering the phone from server without using SMS (cause SMS sending prices too high and I am not making money yet from the application) and sending that verification information to server from the phone. It is very similar to Telegram's phone number verification system.

What I have done so far is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Text, Button } from 'native-base';
import InCallManager from 'react-native-incall-manager';

export default class PhoneVerification extends Component {
    answerPhone() {
        InCallManager.start();
    }
    hangupPhone() {
        InCallManager.stop();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button onPress={this.answerPhone} style={{ marginTop: 600 }}><Text>Answer</Text></Button>
                <Button onPress={this.hangupPhone} style={{ marginTop: 2 }}><Text>Hang up</Text></Button>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

These two buttons do nothing and still default phone answering dialog appears on top of my program when a call made to my phone.

Besides I am open to all of your ideas for cheap phone verification.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I quitted this and start using Google Firebase service.